# Как сконфигурировать Debian для наилучшей производительности?

Tags: debian

Решил поставить Debian, и в связи с этим возникла мысль: а не попробовать скомпилировать его или сконфигуровать при установке для наибольшей максимальной производительности, исходя из архитектуры процессора и т.п? Что для этого надо сделать, какие данные надо знать об архитектуре и какие "телодвижения" делать (бубен и гусли уже лежат рядом). И вообще, а надо ли это, будет ли толк? Или все это лишь ради убийства свободного времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
И вообще, а надо ли это, будет ли толк?
```

Не будет. Преждевременная оптимизация корень многих проблем. Отключить неиспользуемые службы/модули при желании можно, но в минимальной установке их и так в общем-то нет.

Answer (score 2):

Может посмотреть в сторону [gentoo](http://www.gentoo.ru/)? Там почти вся система собирается из исходников изначально.

В Debian есть сорс-пакеты (обычно заканчиваются на -src), которые также можно компилить не разводя внутри несистемную замусоривающую слакварь.

Оптимизация станет тогда заметной, когда оборудование крутое и работает под высокой нагрузкой. В обычной ситуации мой опыт говорит о том, что компилить всё самому - потеря времени. Если только это не добавление функциональности (например, поддержка mysql или что-то подобное), т. е. не ради оптимизации.

Comment: месье знает толк(я по поводу gentoo)но у меня не столько много времени

Comment: [Calculate][1] сэкономит время ))  [1]: http://www.calculate-linux.ru/

Answer (score 1):

А как насчет Arch Linux? Попроще gentoo, но компилить особо самому не надо, есть pacman, который помогает, правда можно обжечься, тк все проги очень часто обновляются и могут возникнуть проблемы с нестабильным софтом. Хотя при чтении мануала можно кучу граблей обойти.

Answer (score 1):

Переходить на другие дистры нет смысла: нужно просто запастись терпением и начать компилить новое яйцо, вот только процесс очень долгий.

Задачи: сделать ядро максимально маленьким, в то же время сохранить все нужные драйвера (это что касается программной части), насчет аппаратной - возможно стоит сделать upgrade железа - тоже ускорит работу!

[Компиляция и установка ядра Linux из исходников в Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/ru/Make-Kpkg).